# Development Server won't render HTML image

Tags: html, django

I'm creating a web application using Django in IntelliJ. My HTML file wants an image but somehow my development server will not show the image at all. If I'm directly opening the HTML file and not using the server, I can see the image. I somehow feel it's an IntelliJ issue. I marked the folder as resources root and tried a bunch of things: creating an images folder at the root level and marking the folder as resources root, putting the image in same folder as HTML file; nothing works.

HTML Code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Page</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<br><br><br>

<center><img src="1.png" height="200" width="200"></center>

{% endblock %}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQM4c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also put the img file inside your static fold. Check this for detail:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files